# Are there additional preset color modes available for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, colors

Windows 10 1903 now offers a light and dark color mode for Windows and Apps. I don't care for either. You may also select a color for the Title bar and Window color which I've done, but still not real happy with it.  I'm color blind and have trouble seeing variations in some of the colors chosen.

Are there any applications that that can set the colors to match previous versions of Windows? I'd really love to see the OS/2 colors from so long ago, less so Hot dog stand.

Comment: I dont think so, all you can add are themes which can change colors....https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13768/desktop-themes-featured

Comment: There are no other modes other than the ones you listed at this time.

Comment: @Moab - The themes I've seen seem to be more of a background image thing, but we used to be able to color tune all the features. I just have trouble seeing the title bar these days on some windows, the tend to blend into the background.  I'll have to look at a third party thing like StarDock's Window Blinds.